# Angular 2. Resource's fails to load in html page

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am building an Angular 2 application. When I `ng-serve` the application, the css and image filed to load, with the following  errors.
[image]

**I have moved the css link above the js link, which did not work.**
**I have also added the full path to the files, instead of the existing.**

*Below is the project structure.*

[image]

*The html code for index.html*

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Front</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">


  <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="resources/js/semantic.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" class="ui" href="resources/css/semantic.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" class="ui" href="resources/css/main.css" />

</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

I have ran into similar issues before with Angularjs and my fix was to, keep moving and changing the links until it worked. Could someone explain why this happens and what are the best practices to avoid this happening in the future.

Comment: make sure path are correct in the angular cli configuration

Comment: Looks like your dev-server doesn't want give you the resources. Something wrong with settings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add your resources to your assets field in the angular-cli.json. This makes them available when you do `ng serve`

```
"assets": [
    "resources"
]
```

This will copy your resources directory into the assets folder (in your build) for both ng build & ng serve. Now replace `resources` with `assets` in your paths

```
<script src="assets/js/semantic.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" class="ui" href="assets/css/semantic.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" class="ui" href="assets/css/main.css" />
```

As an alternative, I would add these files to the angular-cli.json instead of loading them in index.html

```
"styles": [
    "resources/css/semantic.css",
    "resources/css/main.css"
],
"scripts": [
    "resources/js/semantic.min.js"
]
```

I prefer this because those files will be bundled together by webpack, saving on some http requests. Plus I believe the json file is easier to read then index.html, when it comes to dependencies.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you for your quick reply.